# How to find a link in a page based on its href attribute?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, conditional-statements

I am trying to find the first link of my page which url fit to `"AAA"` (example).

I first try to get the links with this href:

```
$('a[href$="AAA"]')
```

Then selec the first one:

```
$('a[href$="AAA"]')[0]
```

Then target the title attribute of this link

```
$('a[href$="AAA"]')[0].attr("title");
```

But all of this return me "undefined", at each step. 
How to do that?

Example anchor:

```
<a href="contents/medias/images/news/news_test_big.jpg" title="Nouvelle réalisation en ligne 1 FR" target="_blank" class="imageLink">
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of one of the actual `<a>` tags?

Comment: Here is one of the links: <a href="contents/medias/images/news/news_test_big.jpg" title="Nouvelle réalisation en ligne 1 FR" target="_blank" class="imageLink"> Thank you ¨!

Comment: @daviddarx I've added the example to your question.

Comment: And which part of the `href` are you trying to match?

Comment: The fullpart "contents/medias/images/news/news_test_big.jpg"

Comment: Should my solution work? Isn't it any other one?

Comment: You can test to see how many elements were found using the `length` property, like `$('a[href=contents/medias/images/news/news_test_big.jpg]').length`. Log that to `console.log()` or `alert()` to see what was matched.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about:

```
$("a[href='AAA']").first().attr("title")
// or
$("a[href='AAA']:first").attr("title")
```

Then it depends if you want the href to be equal to 'AAA', contains it, starts/ends with it. In that case you wouldn't use `href=` but `href$=` for instance. [Neil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093098/jquery-how-to-find-a-link-in-a-page-based-on-its-href-attribute/3093146#3093146) contains the different types of tests you can use.

If you could post your HTML code it would help as well.

Comment: @neil: true, I added it to my answer

Comment: I'm gonna try that, I'll come back in a few minutes

Comment: Shit, it tells me that First isn't a function : 

Erreur : $("a[href='" + imageToDisplay + "']:first").first is not a function
Fichier Source : http://vqt/interface/js/custom/general.js
Ligne : 178

Comment: @daviddarx: it's .first(), not .first

Answer (score 6):

`$('a[href$="AAA"]')` should work fine, but it searches for `href`s that **end** with AAA.

Try:
`$('a[href="AAA"]')` - Equals AAA
Or:
`$('a[href*="AAA"]')` - Contains AAA

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have a matching link (i.e., one that ends with AAA).

```
$('a[href="AAA"]:first').attr('title');
```

should work.

The reason that you are getting undefined for `attr` is that it isn't a jQuery object after you apply the indexer to the result of the query, it's the actual DOM element.  To use `attr`, it needs to still be a jQuery object.  Using the `:first` selector will reduce the results of the query to the first matching one.  Since `attr` will return the value of the first matching attribute, it's not strictly necessary, but I think it makes the intent clearer.  If you go to set the attribute value, `attr` will apply to all of the matching elements so, in that case, it's important -- thus I would use it in both places for clarity.

Comment: +1 - that is true, good point about `[0]` - that's what caused the error. but `$('a[href$="AAA"]')[0].attr("title");` goes too far - it doesn't return `undefined`, but trows an exception: ".attr is not a function"

Answer (score 2):

The way you've written it, you're looking for an href that *ends with* "AAA". Is that your intent?

- `$=` means "ends with"
- `^=` means "starts with"
- `~=` means "contains"

References: [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)